# sqlalchemy OverflowError: into too big to convert using dataframe.to_sql

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to quickly read tables from an Oracle database and write them to a SQL Server database without changing anything.

I read it from the Oracle database using:

```
ocon = cx_Oracle.connect(username,password,dsn,encoding='UTF-8')
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM TABLE",con=ocon)
```

I then try to write the dataframe to the SQL Server using:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create+engine("mssql+pyodbc://user:pass@server:1433/Database?driver=SQL+Server")
df.to_sql(table_name,engine,if_exists='replace')
```

It reads no problem and creates the table in the SQL Server but throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:/Users/user/Desktop/Python/pythonfile.py", line 37, in <module>

    dfotable.to_sql("table_name",engine,if_exists='replace')

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2653, in to_sql

    sql.to_sql(

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 512, in to_sql

    pandas_sql.to_sql(

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1317, in to_sql

    table.insert(chunksize, method=method)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 755, in insert

    exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 669, in _execute_insert

    conn.execute(self.table.insert(), data)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1014, in execute

    return meth(self, multiparams, params)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection

    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1127, in _execute_clauseelement

    ret = self._execute_context(

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1317, in _execute_context

    self._handle_dbapi_exception(

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1515, in _handle_dbapi_exception

    util.raise_(exc_info[1], with_traceback=exc_info[2])

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 178, in raise_

    raise exception

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1257, in _execute_context

    self.dialect.do_executemany(

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\pyodbc.py", line 416, in do_executemany

    super(MSDialect_pyodbc, self).do_executemany(

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 590, in do_executemany

    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)

OverflowError: int too big to convert
```

There are some large numbers in NUMBER types in the Oracle database that I suspect are the issue, I just do not know how to get around it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you already know what the problem is: Oracle's NUMBER datatype supports a much larger range of numbers than SQL Server's INT datatype. Have you considered using DECIMAL or NUMERIC on the SQL Server side?

Comment: I do not get to make that choice, df.to_sql builds the table for me. I do notice that some NUMBER fields are int64 and some are object in the dataframe

Comment: Pre-create the table on SQL Server and then use `if_exists='append'` in .to_sql? You can also specify a schema parameter (dtype, a dict) to .to_sql so you might be able to override it through there. [pandas.DataFrame.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

Comment: It is converting most of them to bigint and some to varchar(max).  The bigint is not large enough to hold the digits, is there a way I can tell to_sql to use lets say numeric instead?  I cannot use append as I write the whole data everytime.

Comment: Did you read the documentation link I gave you? It tells you that the `dtype` parameter uses [SQLAlchemy data types](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html) which include `Numeric(precision=..., scale=..., decimal_return_scale=..., asdecimal=...)` as an option.

Comment: Sorry perhaps I did not explain, I can go through each column and pick a dtype, but I do not see how I can tell  SQLAlchemy to just use NUMERIC if its a NUMBER in oracle without parsing the tables?